# iOS Swift : EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT ) regarding a singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton

My iOS app is returning this error.

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT )

This is occuring on `return Singleton.instance` Here is the code regarding the singleton I am using.

```
class var sharedData : SharedData {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = SharedData()
    }

    return Singleton.instance
}
```

Can someone help me understand this error and help me resolve it? Any suggestions or tips are appreciated it.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of another one you posted later? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083179/ios-swift-calling-a-singleton-method-3-times-causes-app-to-crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Swift 1.2 there is an easier option to create singletons now:

```
class DataManager {
    static let sharedInstance = DataManager()

    /// To deny direct access, make your init function private if you want
    private init() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using a singleton as others have mentioned above,

```
static let sharedData = SharedData()
```

and it was crashing on a real device but not in the simulator. It turns out that I just needed to clean the project and rebuild.
Don't fall for false positives ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all your code with the following:

```
static let sharedData = SharedData()
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a badly named function in my Swift singleton class, that must have been tripping up ARC when it was called. This class initializes another class from a file, and so I ended up with this signature:

```
func initOtherClass(otherClass: NSObject, URL fileURL: NSURL) -> Bool
```

Whoops. Changing the name from `init` to `initialize` solved the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors. I hope this helps to save someone else some time.