# iOS Swift: Calling a singleton method 3 times causes app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton

I have objective / swift code side by side. I am calling a swift singleton method 3 times. After three times it crashes. I have reason to believe this might be a memory problem. Here is my code

ViewController.m

```
-(void)sharedData
{
    // called three times
    sharedData = [SharedData sharedData];
    [sharedData initSyncManager];
}
```

Swift sharedData class

```
class func sharedData() -> SharedData 
{
    struct Singleton 
    {
        static let instance = SharedData()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}

func initSyncManager()
{

}
```

The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT) on this line

```
'return Singleton.instance'
```

I have no idea why this is occurring. I have no code in `initSyncManager` at all and this crash only happens when I use this piece of code

```
[sharedData initSyncManager];
```

If I don't call the method 3 times, the crash doesn't occur.

Comment: I think you have a problem creating singleton, read this http://code.martinrue.com/posts/the-singleton-pattern-in-swift

Comment: I tried the singleton presented and it didn't work sadly.

Comment: Best implementation of an singleton: not at all. I am serious. Step back and ask yourself: "does it really need to be an singleton?", I for example don't use them anymore, I just pass in any object that is needed during creation of a view controller or pass it via properties. Why? because Singletons easily mess up your testing, and memory.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, as I am using this (in Swift 2.1) for creating singleton classes and it's working fine for me:

```
class var sharedInstance: SharedData {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance: SharedData? = nil
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        Static.instance = SharedData()
    }
    return Static.instance!
}

override init() {
    super.init()
    //initialisation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your singleton syntax is working like you expect it to and is creating a new instance with each instantiation. With each instantiation, you're calling `static let instance = SharedData()` ("give me a new instance of shared data") and then returning it.

Try this instead:

```
private let _SharedData = SharedData()

class SharedData {
    class var instance: SharedData {
        return _SharedData
    }
}
```